# Add the "Generated" keyword inside files I generate in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I'm creating a VS2017 extension (VSIX). I will be writing files to the project. Is there a way I can have the "Generated" keyword displayed in those files like currently displayed for t4, less, typescript generated files?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "Generated" keyword. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I have never seen that feature before. Are you sure you don't have a extension that is doing that? (That or I am not very observant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  a Roslyn feature called "Text Adornment". It's used for all sorts of stuff we see in the IDE (an example is the dotted lines that connect open/close braces at the same level).

I try to avoid link-only answers, but the process is quite a bit more involved than is reasonable for a Stack Overflow answer.

Knowing the correct term and reading the following VS2015 article should get you started:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2016/06/27/visual-studio-text-adornment-vsix-using-roslyn/